# Icomparer for objects - or should I be using a SortedSet in the first place?

Tags: vb.net, collections

I want to create a sorted list of objects which are rather like KeyValue pairs, where the Value is itself an Object (quite a complex one, and may be one of a number of subclasses of a base type). The Keys can be duplicated, and I don't mind in which order the Values are sorted - it doesn't even have to be deterministic.

SortedList won't work because of the duplicate keys, so I thought of SortedSet. But to get this to work it seems that I need a comparator which returns a non-zero value when the entries are distinct, so I need to include the Value as part of the comparison.

The need to traverse the list in sorted order happens quite often in the program, so the suggestion that I've seen elsewhere to use a List and sort it when needed is probably not going to work too well.

So my question is: how can I write an Icomparer which compares objects and only produces a 0 result when the objects are in fact the same?

Some fairly minimal VB.NET code follows.

```
  MustInherit Class Item

    Friend Name As String
' I'm not bothering to add the constructor - just assume that "name" gets set somehow 
  End Class

  Public Class ItemA
    Inherits Item   
  End Class

  Public Class ItemB
    Inherits Item    
  End Class

  Class ListEntry
    Friend Key As Integer
    Friend Entry As Item
  End Class

  Class EntryComparer
    Implements IComparer(Of ListEntry)

    Public Function Compare(x As ListEntry, y As ListEntry) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of ListEntry).Compare
      If x.Key > y.Key Then
        Return 1
      ElseIf x.Key < y.Key Then
        Return -1
      Else
        If x.Entry is y.Entry Then
          Return 0
        End If
        '****************************
        ' what do I put in here to compare the Entry fields to ensure that it's only 0 when they're the same object?
        '****************************
      End If
    End Function

  End Class
```

Comment: I would go with a SortedDictionary(Of String, List(Of ListEntry))

Comment: It seems to me that your work to this point indicates that `Item` will implement `IComparable(Of Item)` so that you can delegate to `Item`'s version in your `ListEntry` comparer.

Comment: That is, for your "what goes here" you would return `x.Entry.CompareTo(y.Entry)`.  If you might do anything interesting with these things using Linq, you'll need to override `GetHashCode` as well so that the Linq sequences correctly identify when your objects are considered to be the same.  As well, if your objects are Comparable then they should also be Equatable.

Comment: Thanks both. I'm not sure what the_lotus intends to put into the String key for the dictionary, so can't comment further. Craig's not right in that I don't have a comparer for Item. If I did I could have used it. But I've thought of a solution which might help others with the same problem - see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work (not tested it yet, though):

Give the Item class a shared private field SerialNumber and a field SNo. When New is called, Copy SerialNumber into SNo and increment it. Use this as a secondary key for sorting.